# Expanding a virtual disk Ubuntu 64-bit on Vmware does not work

Tags: hard-drive, vmware

I changed the Hard Disk settings on Ubuntu  64-bit in VMware settings to 60GB and I don't see any changed when I enter into the Ubuntu. What can I do?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the partition. Resizing the virtual disk, just changes how big partitions can be. You can't resize an active filesystem so the easiest way to do this is:

1. Boot the VM to a LiveCD ISO of Ubuntu (what you installed from should do but a later/earlier ISO will work too)
2. When asked click Try Ubuntu
3. Load gparted aka Gnome Partition Editor. I think it's installed on every CD but you might have to grab it from the Software Centre.
4. Find your disk, right click it and go through the resize wizard.
5. Restart the VM without the LiveCD and you should have more free space.